# Can I view previous build logs for a given commit on travis-ci.org?

Tags: travis-ci

By default, on travis-ci.org, a commit pushed to a GitHub repository leads to a build. One can manually restart a build. In that case, can the user access the logs of the previous build?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: @JamesCrowley no

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible, unfortunately: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2993

Though it is on their roadmap apparently. I wish I'd known this wasn't possible before I restarted a build!